# Weird Python Log Error while trying to reinstall Python on Windows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I installed Python on Windows 11 normally after getting the setup from python.org but, by mistake, I deleted the partition Python was installed in (it was E drive). So now, when I rerun the setup, it shows that Python is already installed.

I forced uninstall the old Python and removed all the registery keys with the help of Revo Uninstaller, but now, when I try to install Python again, it isn't installed to the specified folder and when I try to Uninstall the same via setup (after installing), this is the error I come across: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/tekopijiju

So now I want to know if there's a way to *force install* that Python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed.

**The Fix:** I reproduced the path (The E drive) I had deleted and added the same Python folder to it and then clicked the Repair button. It automatically installed Python back to that folder and then I was able to normally uninstall it and install at another location!